# Get all product categories in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to get product categories in WooCommerce, but `get_terms()` function doesn't work for me. I am getting an empty array.

What I am doing wrong? How to get all Woocommerce product category terms?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Product category is a **"custom taxonomy" `product_cat`** used by WooCommerce products.

You need to use `get_terms()`, with the **correct taxonomy**, this way:

```
// Get Woocommerce product categories WP_Term objects
$categories = get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat'] );

// Getting a visual raw output
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $categories ); echo '</pre>';
```

---

You can also get empty product categories using `get_terms()` like:

```
$categories = get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => false] );
```

---

Tested and works (WordPress 3.5+ and WooCommerce 2.4+)… Both should works for you.

You will get something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 83
            [name] => Uncategorized
            [slug] => uncategorized
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 83
            [taxonomy] => product_cat
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 5
            [filter] => raw
            [meta_value] => 1
        )

    [2] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 11
            [name] => Tshirts
            [slug] => tshirts
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 11
            [taxonomy] => product_cat
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 13
            [filter] => raw
            [meta_value] => 2
        )
    // … and so on …
)
```

Comment: Not working. I am getting this

WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [invalid_taxonomy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Invalid taxonomy.
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: Sorry but this code is tested and works… the taxonomy for woocommerce categories is "product_cat'… So you are making some confusions, somewhere.

Comment: You should be using get_the_terms with a check for empty $terms

Answer (score 0):

I got mine out of all product categories, also exclude categories that I don't want to display

```
$taxonomy = "product_cat";
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false, 'exclude' => array( 19 ))); //Exclude Specific Category by ID

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url($thumbnail_id); ?>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="cat-item drop-shadow white-b padding-20 align-center margin-bottom-30">
            <?php 
                echo '<h3 class="uppercase strong blue-2-c margin-bototm-20 equal-height">' . $term->name . '</h3>';
                echo '<div class="item-thumbnail" style="background: url('.$image.');height:150px"></div>'; 
                echo '<a href="' . get_term_link($term->name, $taxonomy) . '" class="button color-blue-2-radial">View Range</a>';
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: get_woocommerce_term_meta is deprecated